# PHP read command output and process in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following working code which read file contain and put into array but now i want to run command and place its output in array for example `ls` command

```
<?php
$path = "file.txt";
$file = fopen($path, 'r');
$data = fread($file, filesize($path));
 fclose($file);
    $lines =  explode(" ",$data);
                echo "<p><h1>$lines[0]</h1></p>";
?>
```

How do i read command output and place in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell-exec):

```
<pre><?php
$output = shell_exec('ls');
print_r($output);
```

Comment: This does not convert the ls output into an array. I need the ls output into an array.

Comment: @RobbieSmith: and you are not able to use `trim` and `explode`?

Answer (score 1):

My Preferred method would be to use [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).  I would be trivial to put the results in an array

```
 $fp = popen ("ls -l", "r");
 $array = array();
 while ($rec = fgets($fp)){
     $array[] = trim($rec);
 }
 // do something cool with array
```